# proving $zw+\frac{16}{zw}=-8\cos(\theta+\beta)$

Tags: complex-numbers

$z,w$ are complex numbers (not zero) that are in the first quarter of Gauss's plane such that:

$$z+\frac{4}{z}=4\sin\theta$$

$$w+\frac{4}{w}=4\sin\beta$$

Need to prove that:  $$zw+\frac{16}{zw}=-8\cos(\theta+\beta)$$

I thought to find $z$ and $w$ by quadratic equation but then i don't know how to choose the sign of the answers.

for example, I don't know if $\sin\theta$ is positive or negative.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: the problem is that $ \theta, \beta \in (0,\pi/2)$ and also $\theta, \beta \in (0,2\pi)$ so both solutions $z=2(\sin\theta \pm i\cos\theta)$ are true but only one true for the proof $z=2(\sin\theta+i\cos\theta)$.

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 0):

how about we turn $z + 4/z = 4\sin \theta$ into a quadratic equation $z^2 - 4\sin \theta z + 4 = 0.$ we can complete the squares by writing $(z - 2\sin \theta)^2 = 4 \sin^2 \theta - 4 = (\pm 2i\cos \theta)^2.$ so $$z = 2(\sin \theta \pm i\cos \theta), \frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{2} (\sin\theta \mp i\cos \theta), w = 2(\sin \beta \pm i\cos \beta), \frac{1}{w} = \frac{1}{2} (\sin \beta \mp i\cos \beta)$$

from this you $$zw = 4[-\cos(\theta + \beta) \pm i \sin(\theta + \beta)], {16 \over zw} = 4 [-\cos(\theta + \beta) \mp i\sin(\theta + \beta)]$$.

adding the last two formula gives $zw + \frac{16}{zw} = -8\cos(\theta + \beta)$ which is at least correct when you put $z = w = 2 \ and \ \theta = \beta = \pi/2.$

Comment: your last part is not clear to me. you can't put $z=w=2$ because it's not in the first quadrant. $z=x+iy,x,y>0$ and also it's not a proof to just pick $\theta=\beta=0.5\pi$.

Comment: i was just error checking with that particular choices; not proving it. see what i wrote before the checking and see if you can find any logical/arithmetical errors.